# Вывод картинки по id из директории после перехода на страницу

Tags: php, mysqli

У меня есть страница с картинками (Some books.php), картинка - ссылка, ведущая на ещё одну страницу (book-1.php).

Мне нужно, чтобы при клике на определённую картинку на Some books.php, на book-1.php (куда меня отправляет) отображалась информация конкретно об этой картинке. При этом, чтобы картинка бралась из папки на сервере, а не из БД (у меня не хотят картинки из БД выводиться).

Путь к картинке хранится в БД в столбце `image` в таблице `book`.

Вот код добавления картинок на страницу, он находится на странице Book.php:

```
<?php
  include_once("header_admin.php");
  include_once("../Connection.php");
  //Если переменная Name передана
  if (isset($_POST["Name"])) {
    //Вставляем данные, подставляя их в запрос
    $file = $_FILES['uploadfile']['name'];
    if (empty($file)) {
        echo "<h2 align='center'>Файл не выбран</a>";
    }else {
         $filetype=$_FILES['uploadfile']['type'];
         $file_name = strstr($file, '.', true);
         $file_ext = strrchr($file, '.');
         $whitelist = array(".jpg", ".jpeg", ".png", ".PNG", ".gif"); 
         if (!in_array($file_ext, $whitelist)) {
            echo '<h2 align="center">Вы пытаетесь загрузить не допустимое расширение файла</h2>';
            exit();
         }else {
                //директория загрузки
                $uploaddir = "book/";
                //новое имя изображения
                $apend=$file_name.'_'.date('YmdHis').rand(100,1000).$file_ext;
                //путь к новому изображению
                $uploadfile = "$uploaddir$apend";
                if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {

                    $sql = mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO `book` (`id_section`,`Name`, `Author`, `BookEdition`, `Yearofpublication`, `Jenre`, `NumberofPages`, `image`) VALUES ('{$_POST['id_section']}','{$_POST['Name']}', '{$_POST['Author']}', '{$_POST['BookEdition']}', '{$_POST['Yearofpublication']}', '{$_POST['Jenre']}', '{$_POST['NumberofPages']}', '{$uploadfile}')");
                    }

                    if ($sql) {
                        echo '<h2 align="center">Данные добавлены</h2>';
                      }else {
                            echo '<h2 align="center">Произошла ошибка. Данные не записанны.</h2>';
                          }                

        }
        }   

  }
?>
```

Вот файл подключения, Connection.php:

```
<?php
    $host = 'localhost';  // Хост, у нас все локально
    $user = 'Neko';    // Имя созданного вами пользователя
    $pass = 'qweqwe'; // Установленный вами пароль пользователю
    $db_name = 'Library';   // Имя базы данных
    $link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db_name); // Соединяемся с базой

    // Ругаемся, если соединение установить не удалось
    if (!$link) {
      echo 'Не могу соединиться с БД. Код ошибки: ' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ', ошибка: ' . mysqli_connect_error();
      exit;
    }
?>
```

Код страницы Some books.php:

```
<?php
session_start();

include_once("Connection.php");
 ?>

  <?php
if (!isset($_SESSION['admin']))
{
  include_once("header.php");
}else{
  include_once("headers/header_admin_1.php");
}
 ?>

<div class="books books-text">


<?php 
$arr = scandir('Admin/book');
foreach($arr as $v) {
if(stripos($v,'.jpg')) echo '<a href="book-1.php"><img src=" Admin/book/'.$v.'" width="155" hegiht="220" />';
}

?>



</div>

<?php
include_once("footer.php");
?>
```

Comment: По части БД я закрыл как дубликат. По части вывода - см. http://phpfaq.ru/newbie/paths

Comment: @Ипатьев тут вопрос больше (и не только) про БД.

Comment: @Suvitruf-AndreiApanasik это что сейчас было? Комментарий модератора? Серьёзно?

Comment: @Ипатьев а что в этом такого?

Comment: @Suvitruf-AndreiApanasik ну если вы считаете что тут вопрос про что-то другое, то наверное можете и сформулировать, про что этот вопрос, при чем так, чтобы это не попадало под категорию "необходимо конкретизировать"

Comment: @Ипатьев не "про другое", а "не только про БД". По-хорошему, вопрос нужно разбить на два, с этим согласен.

Answer (score 0):

Первый файл `first.php`:

```
<?php
$id1 = '1'; // Либо через цикл добавляете картинки, либо вручную получаете id картинок.
$id2 = '2';
$id3 = '3';
// Ставим ссылку на файл через <a>, в href указываем файл, в котором должны выводиться данные и добавляем параметр GET c id картинки
?>
<a href="second.php?image=<?php echo $id1;?>"><img src="book/chikago_20200406121541391.jpg"></a>
<a href="second.php?image=<?php echo $id2;?>"><img src="book/image2.png"></a>
<a href="second.php?image=<?php echo $id3;?>"><img src="book/image3.png"></a>
```

Второй файл `second.php`:

```php
<?php
require_once 'BDconnect.php'; // Подключаем БД из файла

$id = $_GET['image']; // Получаем параметр GET, который передали

// table - название Вашей таблицы
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `book` WHERE `id`=:id"; // Ваш запрос в БД(поиск записи по id)

$req = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$req->bindValue(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_STR); //Данные, которые передаёте в запрос
$req->execute();
$array = $req->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); // Возвращаем значение.

if($array) { // Выводим данные
    echo 'id_section - '.$array['id_section'].'<br>';
    echo 'Name - '.$array['Name'].'<br>';
    echo 'Author - '.$array['Author'].'<br>';
    echo 'BookEdition - '.$array['BookEdition'].'<br>';
    echo 'Yearofpublication - '.$array['Yearofpublication'].'<br>';
    echo 'Jenre - '.$array['Jenre'].'<br>';
    echo 'NumberofPages - '.$array['NumberofPages'].'<br>';
    echo 'ImageSrc - '.$array['image'].'<br>';
}
```

Файл `BDconnect.php`:

```
<?php

try {
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:dbname=bdName;host=localhost', 'BDname', 'BDpass');
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    die($e->getMessage());
}
```

Пример БД:
[image: img]

Запускаете первый файл. 
При нажатии, к примеру, на 2 ссылку - появляется информация:
[image: img2]

Дополнение(после добавления кода):
Вы можете передавать `GET` параметром название самой картинки, вместо `id`

```
foreach($arr as $v) {
if(stripos($v,'.jpg')) echo '<a href="book-1.php?image='.$v.'"><img src=" Admin/book/'.$v.'" width="155" hegiht="220" />';
}
```

И производить поиск в базе по картинке:

```
$ImageSrc = $_GET['image']; // Получаем параметр GET, который передали

// table - название Вашей таблицы
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `book` WHERE `image`=:image"; // Ваш запрос в БД(поиск записи по id)

$req = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$req->bindValue(':image', $ImageSrc, PDO::PARAM_STR); //Данные, которые передаёте в запрос
$req->execute();
$array = $req->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

А дальше выводить как в примере.

Comment: @Neko Подскажите, что осталось не понятным?

Comment: М, Вы тут сами же пишите id, я имею ввиду.. Я не знаю, как получить id картинки, на которую я нажимаю. У меня на странице 1 (Some books.php) выведены картинки из папки в ряд просто.И вот при нажатии на определенную, я не знаю, как получить ее id. Если Вам не сложно, посмотрите пожалуйста, я привела коды страниц в описании к вопросу.

Comment: Простите, кажется я не могу там разговаривать, пишет, что мне нужно 20 репутаций

Comment: Благодарю Вас! Сейчас буду пробовать!

Comment: Теперь он ничего не выводит..

Comment: Подключила, как Вы сказали все, просто пустая страница..

Comment: 4_20200323135656746.jpg
То, то передается. (Я на другую картинку нажала просто, поэтому не chikago)

Это: Array ( [0] => 00000 [1] => [2] => ) после добавления этого->print_r($req->errorInfo());

Comment: Сделала, теперь так: book/chikago_20200406121541391.jpg. И Array ( [0] => 00000 [1] => [2] => )
Станица все еще пустая

Comment: Ее, получилось!

Comment: Вы просто маг! Огромное Вам спасибо!

Comment: Я очень Вам благодарна, спасибо еще раз!

Comment: Ага, постараюсь!

Comment: здравствуйте снова, эм, у меня 1 вопрос есть не по этой теме, я, к сожалению не могу написать Вам в личные сообщения, Вы тут?

Comment: @Neko Если честно, то очень и очень редко. Мы мы можем связаться с Вами каким-либо другим образом, вне данного сообщества. С удовольствием Вам помогу.

Comment: тогда где мы сможем с Вами связаться? Простите, что прошу помощи у Вас, мне больше не к кому обратиться(
Что касается вопроса, то он описан тут: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1115114/%d0%92%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8f-name-%d0%b2%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be-id-%d0%b2-select

Comment: @Neko @Neko Добавьте, пожалуйста, в вопрос строение таблицы `section`. Если в данной таблице хранятся имена, то их точно можно получить. Возможно у Вас просто запись `Name` с большой буквы. Для проверки данных можете отправить запрос типа SELECT `*` FROM `section` и вывести результат. Таким образом будут получены все данные из БД.

Comment: разобралась. Нет. с Name все было в порядке~~