# Вывод поля name вместо id в select

Tags: php, mysqli

```
    <td>Секция</td>
    <td>
        <select name="id_section">
        <option></option>
        <?php
                $sql = mysqli_query($link, 'SELECT `id` FROM `section`');
                while ($result = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
                echo "<option>{$result['id']}</option>";
                }
        ?>
```

Есть код, он вытаскивает из бд из таблицы section - id и записывает его в таблицу book в поле id_section.

```
 $sql = mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO `book` (`id_section`,`Name`, `Author`, `BookEdition`, `Yearofpublication`, `Jenre`, `NumberofPages`, `image`) VALUES ('{$_POST['id_section']}','{$_POST['Name']}', '{$_POST['Author']}', '{$_POST['BookEdition']}', '{$_POST['Yearofpublication']}', '{$_POST['Jenre']}', '{$_POST['NumberofPages']}', '{$uploadfile}')");
                }
```

Мне нужно, чтобы из таблицы доставалось не id селектом, а name, чтобы выбирать по имени а не id. Но если я просто делаю так:

```
        <td>Секция</td>
    <td>
        <select name="id_section">
        <option></option>
        <?php
                $sql = mysqli_query($link, 'SELECT `name` FROM `section`');
                while ($result = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
                echo "<option>{$result['name']}</option>";
                }
        ?>
```

То он ругается и ничего не пишет. Я понимаю в чем дело, но не знаю, как исправить.

Как сделать, чтобы он лез в базу, искал соответствующий выбранному name - id и после подставлял id в таблицу book?

Надеюсь я понятно донесла мысль..

Answer (score 0):

Разобралась. Вот так, если кому нужно:

```
 <?php
        $sql = mysqli_query($link, 'SELECT `id`, `name` FROM `section`');
        while ($result = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
            echo "\t\t<option value=\"{$result['id']}\">{$result['name']}</option>\n";
        }
    ?>
```